# How to say "time span of data" formally?

Tags: technical

I am currently working on a technical documentation for data analytics.
I am wondering how to say "time span of data" formally, as a section name.

For example, I have temperature data per second and it is from 2012 to 2014. I want to say, "time span of data" is 2 years.

How can I say it formally?

Thanks!

Comment: A specified length of time within the continuum is an 'interval'. Of course, you will still need to specify which one (1877-8).

Comment: Thanks you Edwin. Time interval is slightly different from what I want. For example, I have temperature data per second and it is from 2012 to 2014. I want to say, "time span of data" is 2 years and interval is 1 second.

Comment: What's wrong with "Time Span of Data"? It's what I would use. My time is too valuable to tweak my own technical writing like this. Why do you think it's necessary in your case?

Comment: The reason why I am tweaking is that I am not a native english speaker and think there might be some better ways of doing it.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have many apps with current data sets and we call that **range**.  We might use **interval** if it is a common range.

I would say that your data range is (over) two years based on 1 second intervals.

Comment: A problem with range is that it could be understood as the set of the minimum and maximum values between which all data lie.

Answer (score 0):

I think *duration* is the word you're looking for.

Answer (score -1):

I think it could be the independant variable?

Comment: This is not really an answer to this question.  The independent variable is not a phrase that means the time span during which data was collected.  That would be an input or a cause.  See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_and_independent_variables)

Comment: Please do not flag wrong answers as "not an answer". Flag something only when when the normal mechanisms for improving a post (edits, comments, and votes) are inadequate and moderator intervention is necessary. In the case of a wrong answer, consider casting a downvote and leaving a constructive comment.